# Checking Login from form then redirecting to another page

Tags: php, mysql

This was my last attempt that I tried as a last effort:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Customer Login</title>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="login">
                <form name="loginForm" action="loginCheck.php" method="post">
                    <?php require("protect/serverInfo.php"); ?>
                        Email: <input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="35" /><br />
                        Password: <input type="text" name="Password" maxlength="4" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name ="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

loginCheck.php

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['Email'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['Password'];
        require("protect/serverInfo.php");
        $myusername=$_POST[Email]; 
        $mypassword=$_POST[Password];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Email='$myusername' AND Password=$mypassword");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count==1){      
            header('Location: customer.php');
            exit();
        }
        else{
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
?>
```

customer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php
    session_start();
    $myusername = $_SESSION['email']; 
    $mypassword = $_SESSION['password'];
?>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo"success";
?>

</body>

</html>
```

I just need a very simple way to have a form post, the post info to be checked if correct then redirect if correct and pass the post data with it. I have been trying to use sessions and redirects but it doesn't to work quite right. What is the easiest way to accomplish this. At the moment I have been using PHP to check the login info from a MySQL database.

Comment: Can you please post the code that doesn't work quite right?

Comment: I posted my code. I know the Location is no longer a correct URL I just changed it so the url is not seen anymore

Comment: The page gets all the way to the customer page and then just doesnt load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "session_start()" before you do anything else on the page.

Other few things, I avoid storing passwords on a page.. it just seems like a security issue.

Your login form should generate $_SESSION data based on the mysql information returned from the queury, not the form information that the user submited. You need to check against your customers database, to make sure they are an actual customer.

Also, avoid using the "header()" function, especially when working with sessions. I typically have a "redirect" function in php that does something like this...

```
function redirect($url) { 
    echo "<script type='text'/javascript'>window.location='" . $url . "';</script>";
}
```

Comment: yes. If you arent getting an error related to that yet, it might be that you have php error reporting off.

Comment: just know that sessions must be started before you generate any header/content-type on a page.

Comment: Okay I am updating my code and I will keep in mind the things you have told me.

Comment: I still seem to be getting a problem with the session loading. I even just tested making the session $_SESSION['email'] ="hello"; and passing that and trying to echo it but it doesnt seem to hold anything.